# What campsites exist between Gaborone and Windhoek?

Tags: road-trips, camping, off-road, namibia, botswana

We are planning a trip from Gaborone, Botswana to the Namib desert, not far from Windhoek, Namibia. By google its about 15h drive. We are looking for campsites along that route, without diverting too much off course.

We are driving 4x4 with camping gear, personal experience is preferred.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a couple of campsites near Ghanzi which is about halfway between Gaborone and Windhoek.

- [Thakadu Bushcamp](http://www.thakadubushcamp.com)
- [Dqae Qare](http://www.dqae.org)
- [El Fari Bushcamp](http://www.elfari.co.za/)
- [Grassland Bushman Lodge](http://www.grasslandlodge.com/)
- [Tautona Lodge](http://tautonalodge.com/)

I can recommend Thakadu which is basic but clean and has a nice bar and restaurant with a waterhole nearby.

The camp site of Tautona Lodge is fine too but it is a bit far away (more than 1km) of the restaurant.

Answer (score 9):

Recently came back from the trip. Ganzi is an option for better accommodation (more options), and we did stayed there on the way back from Maun. Unfortunately, it was too far from Gaborone for us (670 Km), and added another 100 Km to the trip.

We did found a place to stay in closer to the middle:
**Kang** village which is 420 Km from Gaborone and about 400 Km from the Namibian border post.
There are several guest houses and one [campsite in Kang](http://kangultrastop.com), fueling station and convenience store. The second night we stayed across the Namibian border in [guest farm](http://zeldaguestfarm.com/).

Answer (score 3):

Many, many years later, but for future reference, there is a very nice lodge with a campsite, just north of Kang - Kang Kalahari Rest Stop. I always stay there when I overnight in Kang. There is a pool, and a restaurant (bookings recommended), the drinks are always cold: https://kalaharirest.com/

Nothing wrong with the stops in Kang town, they are clean and convenient. Kalahari Rest Stop has more of a safari atmosphere but an extra 15minutes of travel to get there.

The list of accommodations in Ghanzi are spot on, I always stay at Dqae Qare that is owned by the local c  it is a detour to stay there if you are heading from Kang towards Namibia.